# Best way to retrieve parent and child records together in Java

Tags: design-patterns, dao, spring-jdbc

I have activity and workout tables where workout is a parent and activity is a child meaning each workout contains one or more activities.

### activity

activity_id
name
distance

### workout

workout_id
name
start_time
activity_ids varchar(200) - this columns contains comma separated string values(1,2,3...)

I am using Spring-JDBC for DAO layer and each table has its DAO class (ActivityDAO and WorkoutDAO). I wonder in which DAO I need place code for retrieving workouts along with their activities in one query because WorkoutDAO does not contain RowMapper for building activity objects and vice versa. Can anyone please help me with the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't store comma-separated strings in `activity_ids` column in `workout` table.

Instead, create another table, called `WorkoutActivityMapping` that has one row for each worker to activity mapping. Example schema:

- `workout_activity_mapping_id` - optional
- `workout_id`
- `activity_id`

Define this as a `@OneToMany` mapping in your `Worker` DAO POJO.

I am sure you'd be able to figure out remaining details using the hints above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to do the way you have suggested, but I kept this way as I feel this gives good performance. If I have mapping table that has workout id and activity id, then I need do either select + update + insert or delete+insert whenever activities get updated for each workout. The other thing is that I need to join workout, activity and mapping table to get the workouts along with their activities. That's why I optimized this way. Please suggest if you foresee any problems with this approach

Comment: Relational databases are very good at joins. By burying activityIds in a comma delimited string you are a) making that information harder to retrieve, b) removing the ability to simply join tables to get related data, c) killing any possibility of maintaining referential integrity and d) introducing the possibility of junk being entered in ActivityIds -- it's a string -- anything can be added